# java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected scheme name at index 0:

Tags: java, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, uber-api

I am trying to setup Uber athenaX on my server machine. I think I have completed 80% of things. But for the movement i am struggling with this error.

> ```
> WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Failed to parse resource-request
> java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected scheme name at index 0: :///home/cyclone/randika/athenax/log4j.properties
>     at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
>     at java.net.URI$Parser.failExpecting(URI.java:2854)
>     at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3046)
>     at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:746)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.ConverterUtils.getPathFromYarnURL(ConverterUtils.java:82)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalResourceRequest.<init>(LocalResourceRequest.java:46)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl$RequestResourcesTransition.transition(ContainerImpl.java:614)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl$RequestResourcesTransition.transition(ContainerImpl.java:565)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$MultipleInternalArc.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:385)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:302)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.access$300(StateMachineFactory.java:46)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$InternalStateMachine.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:448)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl.handle(ContainerImpl.java:1129)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl.handle(ContainerImpl.java:84)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl$ContainerEventDispatcher.handle(ContainerManagerImpl.java:1068)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl$ContainerEventDispatcher.handle(ContainerManagerImpl.java:1061)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher.dispatch(AsyncDispatcher.java:184)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher$1.run(AsyncDispatcher.java:110)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> 2018-07-06 09:38:30,635 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1530792582755_0033_01_000001 transitioned from NEW to LOCALIZATION_FAILED
> ```

I think this error occur because of some thing wrong with my athenaX .yaml file this is my .yaml file

> ```
> athenax.master.uri: http://<myip>:8083
> catalog.impl: com.mydashboard.athena.catalog.impl.MydashboardAthenaCatalogProvider
> clusters:
>   CID-62142d19-3125-4736-8a36-726c81a01fbf:
>     yarn.site.location: hdfs:///home/cyclone/randika/athenax/yarn-site.xml
>     athenax.home.dir: hdfs:///home/cyclone/randika/athenax
>     flink.uber.jar.location: hdfs:///home/cyclone/randika/athenax/original-FlinkJob-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
>     localize.resources:
>       - /home/cyclone/randika/athenax/log4j.properties
>     additional.jars:
>       - /home/cyclone/randika/athenax/connectors.jar
> extras:
>   jobstore.leveldb.file: /home/cyclone/randika/athenax/db
> ```

And I tried ***localize.resources:*** as follows

> - /home/cyclone/randika/athenax/log4j.properties

```
- http://home/cyclone/randika/athenax/log4j.properties

- http://<myip>/home/cyclone/randika/athenax/log4j.properties
```

But all of this are not work for me.

Please anyone can help me?..

Comment: Try `file:///home/cyclone/randika/athenax/log4j.properties`, etc.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your quick response seems like it's OK. but it will end up with another error related to same problem

java.io.IOException: Resource file:/home/cyclone/randika/athenax/log4j.properties changed on src filesystem (expected 1526902625000, was 1530807962000

Comment: That's a different problem; please ask it as a separate question.